# Virtual Machine on Hyper-V Server Manager is gone

Tags: hyper-v

After trying to delete snapshots from a vm... the vm somehow isn't shown anymore in the hyper-v manager nor isn't running... rebooted and still nothing. but the files are there. vm files, hdd and snapshots... what can i do?

Thanks for helping.

windows 2008 r2 x64

Comment: ok this will sound strange but if you open an elevated command prompt and type "wmic os" what happens do you get an invalid class error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thank god i worked it out!

the culprit was the double ">" in the vm xml... it looked like this:

```
</configuration>>
```

edited the file to look like this:

```
</configuration>
```

now it's back to the the hyper v manager! just had an error when booting the vm about the network adapter but that was easy to fix through the vm settings.

now just need to merge the snapshots to the main vhd just in case...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply re-create the VM container and attach the existing VHD to it, then boot the VM?

Comment: yeah but how to do it with the snapshots?

Comment: i mean my .vhd is from 20/10/2012 and the snapshots are from 08/11/2012 and 25/11/2012 i need the vm updated